# Asterisk 15.3 vs Asterisk 14.6 '200 OK' Contact field differences

Tags: asterisk

Does anyone know why Asterisk 15.3 uses its Public IP-Address in the Contact field in a '200 OK' from an INVITE, but Asterisk 14.6 uses its Private IP-Address?

Can this be manipulated in Asterisk?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

In Asterisk 15, ICE support is enabled by default.  In 14, it's disabled by default.  See the icesupport option in /etc/asterisk/rtp.conf

Comment: Thank you,  I do have icesupport=true in both versions.

Comment: I forgot to add that even though icesupport is true in both rtp.conf files, I still have the same problem.